# SOCKET error on compiling bitcoin source code

Tags: c++, windows, build, makefile, bitcoin

I'm going to compile BitCoinD with some edits. When I try to do

```
mingw32-make -f makefile.mingw
```

it returns me this:

```
g++ -c -mthreads -O2 -w -Wall -Wextra -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-par
ameter -g -DWIN32 -D_WINDOWS -DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB -DBOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE -D
USE_IPV6 -DUSE_IPV6=1 -IC:/Users/Proprietario/Desktop/litecoin-master-0.8/src/le
veldb/include -IC:/Users/Proprietario/Desktop/litecoin-master-0.8/src/leveldb/he
lpers -I"C:/Users/Proprietario/Desktop/litecoin-master-0.8/src" -I"c:/MinGW/deps
/boost_1_54_0" -I"c:/MinGW/deps/db-4.7.25.NC/build_unix" -I"c:/MinGW/deps/openss
l-1.0.0d/include" -o obj/alert.o alert.cpp
In file included from netbase.h:11:0,
                 from util.h:30,
                 from alert.h:13,
                 from alert.cpp:11:
compat.h:29:15: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef u_int SOCKET'
In file included from c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.3/..
/../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winsock2.h:49:0,
                 from compat.h:15,
                 from netbase.h:11,
                 from util.h:30,
                 from alert.h:13,
                 from alert.cpp:11:
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-m
ingw32/include/psdk_inc/_socket_types.h:11:18: error: 'SOCKET' has a previous de
claration as 'typedef UINT_PTR SOCKET'
mingw32-make: *** [obj/alert.o] Error 1
```

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`compat.h:29:15: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef u_int SOCKET'`

and

`_socket_types.h:11:18: error: 'SOCKET' has a previous de
claration as 'typedef UINT_PTR SOCKET'`

Tells you that the type `SOCKET` has been defined in two different ways.
Get rid of or modify one of those typedefs.

It's also possible that you're including something you don't need to be including.

Comment: @kristianp I believe the topic creator originally left a comment about what he did, but quickly deleted it. Unfortunately I don't remember which route he took.